git hooks on windows returns error ".hooks/post-merge: line 3: php: command not found", but the command exists
In windows I have this post-merge git hook:
#!/bin/sh

php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionSeeder

When I do a pull, I get this error:

.hooks/post-merge: line 3: php: command not found

What I know:

if I execute the exact same command from windows terminal, it works
php.exe is in my user path

Any idea why the git hook does not find php.exe?

Is it in $PATH? Probably not.... as an alternative, you can provide the full path to the php binary.

@eftshift0 it is in the path. I am sure about that.

So, if you type which php, it gives you the path to the php binary, right?

I am on windows, I do not have the "which" command. But php.exe is in the user path, I am sure about that. Maybe git uses another user?

could be the #!/bin/sh command? Probably I have to use #!/bin/bash

Git pre/post commit scripts are not executed in a regular terminal. Instead Git uses the GIT CMD (see start menu). Another potential problem could be your $PATH environment. If you have changed it recently not all processes may have applied the update (AFAIR this has to be implemented in the process). Therefore the git commit hook could be executed with the old $PATH value. Better log off and on again or reboot your system to make sure all processes use the updated PATH.

@Robert If I launch "GIT CMD" from windows start menu, and in the open terminal I execute "php -v", I get the current php version installed

Just to make sure: You are executing the git command in the regular Windows terminal (cmd, powerhsell, ..) not in a WSL environment?

Yes, in a regular windows terminal, NO WSL environment.
